# SQL session/connection variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find some equivalent to session variables in SQL. I want to be able to store and retrieve just a number but each connection to the database has a different number. It needs to persist from one batch to the next on the same connection.

I did have a solution that used a global cursor like this.

```
IF (SELECT CURSOR_STATUS('global','ChangeSet')) >= 0 
BEGIN --Close and deallocate the cursor
    Close ChangeSet
    DEALLOCATE ChangeSet
END

--Create a new cursor
DECLARE ChangeSet CURSOR GLOBAL STATIC FOR
SELECT ChangeSet = @ChangeSet

--Open the cursor
OPEN ChangeSet
```

Each connection would have a different cursor so it worked, but this is not usable inside of a view. I guess if somebody can show me how to read this in a view that would be cool too.

I'm using MS SQL Server btw.

Answer (score 6):

The [`CONTEXT_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx) property may be what you're looking for - it enables you to set and read a connection-specific binary value.

You could encode your numeric value to binary and store it in this property.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from SQL 2016

```sql
EXEC sys.sp_set_session_context @key = N'language', @value = 'English';  
SELECT SESSION_CONTEXT(N'language');
```

Answer (score 0):

A temporary table survives a batch (including `go`).  It's still connection specific:

```
create table #temp (val float)
insert #temp values (3.14)
go
select * from #temp
```

Comment: I thought this was going to work but turns out temp tables can't be used in views either. It also has some other strange scope properties that means I can't create it in a stored procedure and then read it in another, but I can set it outside of a stored procedure and then read it in one.